# Add extra parameter in SignalR method without breaking changes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I want to pass additional parameter via Signalr without any breaking changes.

SignalR hub web api side signalr nuget package being used is "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR" Version="1.0.3".
Client side nuget package being used is "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client" Version="1.0.3" />

Initial code at signalr hub web api side is given below-

```
public async Task<bool> SendResponse(string uniqueId, string param1, string param2, string param3, string param4, string param5, string param6)
{
    await HubContext.Clients.Group(uniqueId).SendAsync("SendResponse", param1, param2, param3, param4, param5,param6);
    return true;
}
```

Initial code at client side-

```
Connection.On<string, string, string, string, string, string>("SendResponse",
async (param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6) =>
{
    //code here.
});
```

This client side code is shared with everyone via a nuget package and its on application owner when he want to update the nuget package.

Till now everything is working fine a changed requirement (pass a new parameter with response) arise.

To fulfill this requirement I have made below given code changes in signalr hub side-

```
public async Task<bool> SendResponse(string uniqueId, string param1, string param2, string param3, string param4, string param5, string param6, string param7)
{
    //send 6 parameters in old method so that client code can continue his work without updating client side code changes.
    await HubContext.Clients.Group(uniqueId).SendAsync("SendResponse", param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6);
    //Send 7 parameters in new method.
    await HubContext.Clients.Group(uniqueId).SendAsync("SendResponse2", param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6, param7);    
    return true;
}
```

SignalR is hub web api service updated with these code changes and issue start arise after that.
Client applications who has old SignalR client code start receiving errors-

```
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.InvalidDataException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.Json.dll
Invocation provides 7 argument(s) but target expects 0.
```

Changes at client side for SendResponse2 method-

```
Connection.On<string, string, string, string, string, string, string>("SendResponse2",
    async (param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6, param7) =>
    {
        //code here.
    });
```

Please let me know how can I fix this issue.
The main important thing for me is that my end user should work fine if they have updated the client side code or not.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you can't safely add a parameter right now. SignalR doesn't support the full set of C# invocation semantics. For example, we don't support overloads, or default parameters. If this is something you'd be interested in, please feel free to file an issue on https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues !

A good way to make methods like this extensible is to take a single parameter object instead of multiple parameters:

```
public class MyParams
{
     public string Param1 { get; set; }
     public int Param2 { get; set; }
     public double Param3 { get; set; }
}

public void MyHubMethod(MyParams p)
{
}
```

Then, when you need to add a parameter you can add a property to this class (`Param4`). If an older client comes along and invokes the method **without** providing `Param4`, then that value will simply be left as the default (i.e. `null` for a reference type, `0` for an `int`, etc.).

Comment: Hi @Andrew, your suggestion is best if we start our project from start, but I am stuck in the current situation. I have also posted question on Git https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/3157.